# left shift on short produces zero

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

As 'byte' is 8-bit and 'short' is 16-bit in Java, I believe this should --

```
byte[] packet = reader.readPacket();
short sh;
sh = (short)packet[1];          //packet[1] holds '0xff'
sh <<= 8;
sh &= 0xFF;
System.out.print(sh+" ");
```

produce some big positive value, since lower 8bits are promoted to higher 8 bits.

Instead I receive a '0' (zero). Why does it happen so?

Comment: What do you think `sh &= 0xFF;` does?

Comment: Maybe it should be 0xFFFF?

Comment: When you use `<<= 8`, you make the lower bits all 0, so when you mask only the lower bits, you just get zero.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is shifting the initial value to the left:

```
0000 0000 1111 1111  
<<=8  
1111 1111 0000 0000
```

Then, you're doing a bitwise AND with 0xFF:

```
1100 0011 0000 0000  
&  
0000 0000 1111 1111  
==  
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Thus, your end result is 0.

Comment: The OP said in his comments that `0xff` is the initial value. Is `1101 0011 1100 0011` just meant as a generic example value?

Comment: ah, wasn't paying attention to that comment.  That was just an example; he'd get the same result no matter what the initial value was.

Comment: I agree, answer would be the same. Just checking that I wasn't **that** rusty on my hex :)

Answer (score 3):

The code first shifts left 8 places. So you have all the right most 8 bits set to 0.

Then you AND it with 0xFF which has left most 8 bits 0.

So your final result is all 0's!

Additional comment: It is a good practice to avoid using short for Java as Java typecasts everything below int as int. Also, it is not clear from your code what output you expected. If you add additional information, it will be easy to spot exactly what is needed to be done for the logic you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this step-by-step:

```
sh = (short)0xff;  //Since you said that packet[1] holds '0xff'
```

So now `sh = 0x00ff`. Next, consider the shift `sh <<= 8;`. Afterwards, `sh = 0xff00`.

I'll leave the last `sh &= 0xFF;` to you (should hopefully be clear why the `&` op is setting `sh` to 0).